# How to track changes for certain database tables?

Tags: sql, db2, rad

I have program that takes user and updates information about him/her in five tables. The process is fairly sophisticated as it takes many steps(pages) to complete. I have logs, sysout and syserr statements that helps me to find sql queries in IDE console but it doesn't have all of them. I've already spend many days to catch other missing queries by debugging but no luck so far. The reason why I am doing this is because I want to automate user information updates so I don't have to go through every page entering user details manually.

I wonder if I could just have some technique that will show me database table changes as I already know table names, by changes I mean whether it was update or insert statements and what exactly changed(column name and value inserted/updated). Any advice is greatly appreciated. I have IBM RAD and DB2 database. Thanks.

Comment: I mean, a SQL Trace would get you close to that.

Comment: What DB2 version/platform?

Comment: Doesn't DB2 support the use of triggers? Except of massively loading environemnts - such as BI - a trigger would be my tool of choice in order to track changes on a SQL DB.

Comment: @mustaccio Version 10

Answer (score 0):

In DB2 you can track basic auditing information.

DB2 can track what data was modified, who modified the data, and the SQL operation that modified the data.

To track when data was modified, define your table as a system-period temporal table. The row-begin and row-end columns in the associated history table contain information about when data modifications occurred.

To track who and what SQL modified the data, you can use non-deterministic generated expression columns. These columns can contain values that are helpful for auditing purposes, such as the value of the CURRENT SQLID special register at the time that the data was modified. Possible values for non-deterministic generated expression columns are defined in the syntax for the CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements.

For example

```
CREATE TABLE TempTable (balance INT, 
              userId VARCHAR(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS  ( SESSION_USER ) ,  
              opCode CHAR(1) 
                          GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( DATA CHANGE OPERATION )  
              ... SYSTEM PERIOD (SYS_START, SYS_END));
```

The userId column stores who modified the data. This column is defined as a non-deterministic generated expression column that contains the value of SESSION_USER special register.

The opCode column stores the SQL operation that modified the data. This column is defined as a non-deterministic generated expression column and stores a value that indicates the type of SQL operation.

Suppose that you then use the following statements to create a history table for TempTable and to associate that history table with TempTable:

```
CREATE TABLE TempTable_HISTORY (balance INT, user_id VARCHAR(128) , op_code CHAR(1) ... );

ALTER TABLE TempTable ADD VERSIONING 
                 USE HISTORY TABLE TempTable_HISTORY     ON DELETE ADD EXTRA ROW;
```

Answer (score 0):

Capturing SQL statements for a limited number of tables and a limited time - as far as I understand your problem - could be solved with the DB2 Audit facility.

```
create audit policy tabsql categories execute status both error type normal

audit <tabname> using policy tabsql
```

You have to have SECADM rights in theh database and the second command will start the audit process. You can stop it with

```
audit <tabname> remove policy
```

Check out the

> db2audit

command to configure paths and extract the data from the audit file to a delimited file which then could be loaded again into the database.
The necessarfy tables can be created with the provided sqllib/misc/db2audit.ddl script. You will need the query the EXECUTE table for your SQL details

Please note that audit can capture huge amounts of data so make sure to switch it off again after you have catured the necessary information.